# datepicker does not work with global variale as parameter

Tags: jquery

I want to use a global variable in a parameter-
Here is my code-

```
$( ".datePickerExpiry" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    yearRange: passportIssueYear+': 2050'
});
```

"passportIssueYear" is the global variable and hold the year.

Comment: whats the error you are getting? there is workaround of using `option` API but lets find whats your current problem

Comment: ANY ERROR IN YOUR BROWSER CONSOLE???

Comment: Date picker only range the year 2050. Does not start from that variable.

Comment: Ok and then what is this variable `passportIssueYear`???

Comment: @A.Wolff It is a year like-1960

Comment: It works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/r9d07m7u/  So how do you debug it? Sounds like `passportIssueYear` is `undefined`. I guess it comes from some ajax request...

Comment: works far as far as I can tell, are you sure the var passportIssueYear is a global? look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/w6dd90cg/

Comment: @A.Wolff.. yeah right.. if its coming from ajax and OP is setting it up before response comes, then that might problem.

Comment: @JeremyC. I save my code and its not working on it.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes it is. See my code- [https://jsfiddle.net/s5d0ku5w/]

Comment: we don't know what your code is so how are we supposed to figure it out? your fiddle doesn't exist

Comment: @JeremyC. I save on your jsfiddle

Comment: I think the function you need on that datepicker isn't .change, let me look it up again, I think I know the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work in a fiddle: (you need to reinitialize the datepicker when the value of your year changes)

NOTE: had to change your datepicker date format because the new Date() function didn't support the format you were using (hope it's not too big of a deal)

```
function setIssuePicker(){
    $(".datePickerIssue").datepicker("destroy");
    $( ".datePickerIssue" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: birthDateYear+': '+ new Date().getFullYear()
});
}
var birthDateYear = 2015;


$( ".datePickerBirthDate" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: '1950 : ' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        var birthDate = new Date(dateText);
        birthDateYear = birthDate.getFullYear();
        setIssuePicker();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s5d0ku5w/2/)

Comment: I having problem to your fiddle when i change my "datePickerBirthDate".

Suppose i set for the first time 2000 as year. Now its fine, i can select "DateOfIssue" From 2000.

But if i change it to 1990at this time then the "dateOfIssue" shows the previous year not the current.

Comment: set this $(".datePickerIssue").datepicker("destroy"); as the first line in setIssuePicker

Answer (score 0):

Its working.. checkout below.

```js
var passportIssueYear  = 2014

$(function(){

$( ".datePickerExpiry" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    yearRange: passportIssueYear+': 2050'
});
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryuhttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.cssi/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="datePickerExpiry">
```